# Определить алгоритм сжатия данных

Tags: алгоритм, сжатие, байты

Входные байты (не сжаты):

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2421E420E8AAEBD7
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2421C318FAFAFBFE
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420C3185A5E7A7E
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC318821028282A00
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420C210ABABABAA
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0421C31803FFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2421C318A2FFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0421C318F0FFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420C210FAAAAAAA
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420C210FFAAAAAA
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420C210ABAAAAAA
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420C210BAAAAAAA
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420A210FAFAEAAA
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE420A210FFDFFF
```

Результат (сжатые байты):

```
9B0588082421E420E8AAEBD760108807
21C318FAFAFBFE99058808E420C3185A
5E7A7E99058807C318821028282A6040
8808E420C210ABABABAA990588050421
C31803E80810508801A2E80810208801
F0E80810408803FAAAAA60401010900E
7060037010058801BA7010038805A210
FAFAEA7010038803FFDFFF
```

Есть маркер '88', после которого указан размер не сжатых байт.
Хотелось бы узнать у знатоков, каким алгоритмом сжаты данные?